# Pandas Series Sort

Tags: python, pandas

I want to sort digit written in object form as given below:

````
series = pd.Series(["tree", "one", "two"])
series
0 three
1 one
2 two

 but I need after sorting in the form of
1 one
3 two
0 three
```
````

Answer (score 1):

So the challenge will be that you cant sort by the strings. What you could do is using an approach as discussed [here](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-convert-numbers-to-words-in-Python) to get a dictionary written_nmber: number.
Example:

```
{"one": 1, "two": 2, ...}
```

Then you create a DataFrame out of your Series, add the numeric values and sort by them:

```
series = pd.Series(["three", "one", "two"])
number_dict = {"one" : 1, "two" : 2, "three" : 3}
aux_df = pd.DataFrame()
aux_df["written_numbers"] = series
aux_df["numeric_numbers"] = aux_df.written_numbers.map(number_dict)
sorted_series = aux_df.sort_values("numeric_numbers")["written_numbers"]
```

Answer (score 0):

There is this nice implementation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493174/is-there-a-way-to-convert-number-words-to-integers) that you can use to convert your written numbers into integers:

```
def text2int(textnum, numwords={}):
    if not numwords:
      units = [
        "zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight",
        "nine", "ten", "eleven", "twelve", "thirteen", "fourteen", "fifteen",
        "sixteen", "seventeen", "eighteen", "nineteen",
      ]

      tens = ["", "", "twenty", "thirty", "forty", "fifty", "sixty", "seventy", "eighty", "ninety"]

      scales = ["hundred", "thousand", "million", "billion", "trillion"]

      numwords["and"] = (1, 0)
      for idx, word in enumerate(units):    numwords[word] = (1, idx)
      for idx, word in enumerate(tens):     numwords[word] = (1, idx * 10)
      for idx, word in enumerate(scales):   numwords[word] = (10 ** (idx * 3 or 2), 0)

    current = result = 0
    for word in textnum.split():
        if word not in numwords:
          raise Exception("Illegal word: " + word)

        scale, increment = numwords[word]
        current = current * scale + increment
        if scale > 100:
            result += current
            current = 0

    return result + current
```

After that, sorting them is easy:

```
numbers = pd.DataFrame({'written_numbers':['two hundred', 'one', 'twenty', 'seven']})
numbers['integers'] = numbers.written_numbers.apply(lambda x: text2int(x))
sorted_numbers = numbers.sort_values(by='integers')
sorted_numbers
```

Outputs:

```
    written_numbers integers
1   one             1
3   seven           7
2   twenty          20
0   two hundred     200
```